# How to Connect with one fragment with another fragment

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-fragments

> I am new with Fragment. My problem is how to do it, when I selected my  (OneFragment.java) radio button is Selected then another (Threefragment.java) will also be selected and show the data.

> Here some Images Of My Product, I hope anyone can help me out.

> [This is My FirstFragment.Java](https://i.stack.imgur.com/830VA.png)

> [This is My ThirdFragment.Java](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sBrB0.png)

Comment: images arent helping, some code would be helpful. in short: you should create an `interface` implemented by both `Fragment`s, register them in `Activity` (keep in some array) and call in any fragment `getActivity().notifyAllListeners(value)`. `notifyAllListeners` would be a method in which you should iterate through array of registered interfaces (so `Fragment`s) with passing desired `value`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are many ways to communicate between fragments. The best way is to use fragment managers.

In fragment 3, initialize the listener.

```
setFragmentResultListener("requestKey") { key, bundle ->
    // Any type can be passed via to the bundle
    val result = bundle.getString("data")
    // Do something with the result...
}
```

From fragment 1, you can pass the data with the help of request keys and bundle.

```
setFragmentResult("requestKey", Bundle())
```

Make sure the fragment version is up to date.

Answer (score 0):

You can use shared `ViewModel` to passing the data between fragments using observables to retain the values and shows in any fragment through shared ViewModel.
Here is proper [Implementation](https://appchance.com/blog/passing-data-between-fragments-using-viewmodel) of shared `ViewModel`